# How to Check if an NFT belongs to an address in solidity using only the address of the NFT instead of the tokenId

Tags: solidity, erc-721, openzeppelin

I am trying to write a function in solidity that accepts an `nftAddress` parameter with `address` type, then checks to see if `nftAddress` belongs to the `msg.sender`.

I figured I can use OpenZeppelin's ERC721 `ownerOf()` function to check but it requires that you pass in the `tokenId`of the NFT.

Is there a way to instead pass in the `tokenId` of the NFT, you pass in the address of the NFT?  Thanks

Comment: the feature you require would need the token contract to add another map variable, and that will cost a lot of storage (+ increase in code complexity), that's why nobody is doing it this way. You will have to keep track of all token ids using events

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you wish to get tokenId that belong to some owner?

Most NFTs follow the ERC721 or ERC1155 standard, so you can check out which functions are supported [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721-balanceOf-address-).

TO sum it up, there is no function that would give you the token ids that some address holds, but you could use `balanceOf(owner)` function, which tells you how many NFTs an owner holds and then iterate through all the ids with `ownerOf(tokenId)`

Comment: I want to check to see if an NFT's address belongs to a particular address

Comment: As for NFT's address you mean token or contract?

Comment: The NFT's contract

Comment: I see. A contract only has an owner if it is ownable: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/access-control If it does have it, you can get the owner using owner().